Need document to requeat access to fortify
Followed
https://talech.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/NE/pages/2021392422/Fortify+Blackduck+Scan+Self-Service
to login and wanted to
Locate scan results in Fortify portal
Tried to Login to https://fortifyssc.us.bank-dns.com/
Expected :
Dashboard of fortify
After logging into Fortify, click Applications up top.
Actual Result :
Getting authentification failure error , also tried to create account but getting Unable to submit request. The service is not configured.
So need document to requeat access to fortify with default and sample values for the mandatory  fields,

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
